# How to fix invalid use of group function in sql

Tags: sql, where-clause

I was trying to write a code that look for specific rows in selected column, using `where`, however when I add a `where` it doesn't work, when before putting `Where` clause it worked fine.

So there is tables `step`, `step_taken`: 
`step` has `id`, `title` column;
 `step_taken` has `id`, `user_id`, `step_id`

I wanted to get title of steps that have been taken more than 2 times by users.

So first I wrote

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*)
FROM step 
JOIN step_taken ON step.id = step_taken.step_id 
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Then it showed the result fine from the one that has count 1 to 10.

But when I add

```
WHERE COUNT(*) > 2
```

like

```
SELECT title, count(*)
FROM step   
JOIN step_taken ON step.id = step_taken.step_id 
WHERE COUNT(*) > 2
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

I get an error.

How can I fix the error and get the result with ones only bigger than count value 2?

I wanted to select rows with count greater than 2 but when I used `WHERE` clause, it created an error.

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. And `HAVING` goes just after `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use aggregation functions in a `HAVING` clause. Change your query to this:

```
SELECT title, count(*)
FROM step join step_taken
ON step.id=step_taken.step_id 
GROUP BY title
HAVING count(*)>2
ORDER BY count(*);
```

Note by using a column alias you can make your query more readable:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*) AS title_count
FROM step 
JOIN step_taken ON step.id = step_taken.step_id 
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY title_count;
```

Note that in some DBMS, such as MySQL, you can also use the column alias in the `HAVING` clause i.e.

```
HAVING title_count > 2
```